# how to start an angular.dart app

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am on angulardart 0.11.0 and this is my code for main.dart:

```dart
library my_app_main;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

import 'package:my_app/src/something.dart';

class MyModule extends Module {
  MyModule() {
    bind(MyAppCtrl);
    bind(MyComp);
  }
}

main() {
  applicationFactory()
    .addModule(new MyModule())
    .run();
}
```

I get syntactic errors:

- angular.dart import is 'unused'
- 'Module' is an 'undefined class'

I have tried deleting and rebuilding the packages directory, pubspec file, etc. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was caused by the angular files becoming corrupted in the pub cache. As was pointed out here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-dart/WiZuIwxTDb4) - thanks Günter! - the solution is to repair the pub cache by doing 'pub cache repair' or at least 'pub cache add angular'

Answer (score 0):

`angular.dart import is 'unused'` is just a warning, so you don't really need to worry about it.

You're seeing `'Module' is an 'undefined class'` because you're not importing the di library.  Add
`import 'package:di/di.dart';` to your imports and it should run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right that 'import unused"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right that 'import unused' is just a warning but I don't see why I'm getting it, as this code is effectively the code given in the current angulardart tutorial. Furthermore, the tutorial doesn't import 'di' in order to use 'Module' - have a look at https://angulardart.org/tutorial/03-ch01-creating-your-first-app.html and, anyway, importing it doesn't solve the problem. Something else must be wrong.